# Show that $\prod_{i=2}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right) = \frac{n+1}{2n}$for $n \in \Bbb{N}$, $ n \ge 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Use mathematical induction to shoe that fpr any $n\in N$, if $n\ge2$, then
$$\prod_{i=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)=\frac{n+1}{2n}$$

[image]

So I understand what's happening up until the first red circle. Why does 1 - become $(n+1)^2$?

When expanding $(n+1)^2$ I thought it'd be $n^2+2$, why is there an extra $n+1$?

Comment: Another simple proof, $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\dfrac{1}{i^2}\right)=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\dfrac{i^2-1}{i^2}\right)=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\dfrac{i+1}{i}\right)\displaystyle\prod_{i=2}^n\left(\dfrac{i-1}{i}\right)\left(\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right)=\left(\dfrac{n+1}{2n}\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\color{blue}{1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\color{blue}{\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)^2}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{(n+1)^2-1}{(n+1)^2}$$

Now use $$(a+b)^2=(a+b)(a+b)=a^2+ab+ab+b^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$

to get $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$

Comment: How  come the 1 - goes on the top line?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: yes thank youu.